# How to install AutoMapper.Collection into a aspnet boilplate asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

how do I install AutoMapper.Collection to an abp boilerplate asp.net core project?

Answer (score -2):

1. Open `YourProject.Core.csproj` file in notepad.
2. Add the AutoMapper.Collection like shown in the below code block and save the file.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <TargetFrameworks>net461;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
    <AssemblyName>AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core</PackageId>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <RootNamespace>AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Localization\SourceFiles\*.json" Exclude="bin\**;obj\**;**\*.xproj;packages\**;@(EmbeddedResource)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Abp" Version="3.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.0" />

    <!-- **** Add the below line **** -->
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Collection" Version="3.1.3" />

  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

3. Open CMD (command line) and run `dotnet restore` in the folder where `YourProject.Core.csproj` located.

```
c:\GitHub\YourProject\src\AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Core> dotnet restore
```

Comment: "Open the csproj file in notepad", sure, because that's much faster than doing right-click and select "Edit csproj" from the Visual Studio window that you already have opened...

Comment: Do I need to configure anything else in the asp.net core project, 

ie documentation specifies the following for EF: 

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.AddCollectionMappers(); // Configuration code }); 

and 

Mapper.Initialize(cfg => { cfg.AddCollectionMappers(); cfg.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkPrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<DB>>(); // Configuration code }); 

I'm using asp.net boilerplate core template, does the abp.automapper already handle the initialization required ?